# Sending Http requests from a webbrowser to HttpListener

Tags: c#, firefox, httplistener

I've set up an HttpListener running on port 8086 on my custom server application, which works with JSON and XML over sockets. I can't change my server application to any other implementation, I am stuck with it for now.

I'm a bit new to Http, so feel free to correct my naviety below! I've searched, but can't find anything that deals with my exact problem.

When I use Hurl.it to send an HttpRequest to the server, the GetContext function fires no problem and I am able to send an html response back to Hurl.it.

Now, the question is, I want to be able to send out Reset Password email links in the form of "http://myip:PORT/resetpasswordseed=74283235" and have a browser be able to receive, parse and display a dynamically generated html form. (I will also need to add SSL to this a bit later, as I don't want a newly updated password being sent as plain text in a URL.)

Now, when I click the URL link http://myserverip:port/resetpassword with Edge or Firefox the GetContext function does not fire and the web browser times out. Have I missed something or am I trying to do something that is not possible? I don't get an error message or an exception or anything.

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers

Craig.

Comment: Can "hurl.it" hit the same URL that fails in the browser?

Comment: Yes. The GetContext() (I'm using the blocking version for the moment) function fires no problem and is able to extract the parameters that are sent.

Comment: sounds rather like a firewall issue to me then.

Comment: Could be. The ports appear to work correctly, as the routers port 5000 is forwarded to 8086. I've got exceptions set up in windows firewall and the NAT forwarding seems to work correctly...

Comment: Right. I've played with this more. Ports are open and working when I use a WebRequest.CreateHttp(URL) - when I connect to the URL:PORTNUMBER with any web-browser the BeginGetContext function does not fire. I can do this with any .NET function - and my money is on some sort of security 'feature' in the web browsers. The connection appears to proceed, then it just times out with no further information - like I said, the GetContext function  does not fire no matter what - What is going on here? Can I actually serve Html data using HttpListener or have I missed something stupid?